# Test execution output of a command before a pipe

Tags: pipe, stdout, testing, tee, stderr

I would like to test the execution of a php script that redirect its stdout and stderr to a file with `tee`.

```
php /path/to/script --param 2>&1 | tee -a  /path/to/log
if ( test $? -ne 0 ); then
    exit 2
fi
```

The last code tests the execution of the `tee -a` even if the php ocmmand fails.

How can I exploit `$?` or something similar to test the php script not the whole line ?